# Wrong pagination in MAX() query of postgres

Tags: typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

This is my query to fetch the latest message from each room:

```
SELECT MAX
    ( "Messages"."id" ) AS messageId,
    "Rooms"."id" 
FROM
    "RoomUsers"
    INNER JOIN "Rooms" ON "RoomUsers"."roomId" = "Rooms"."id"
    INNER JOIN "Conversations" ON "Conversations"."roomId" = "Rooms"."id"
    INNER JOIN "Messages" ON "Messages"."conversationId" = "Conversations"."id" 
WHERE
    "RoomUsers"."userId" = 51
GROUP BY
    "Rooms"."id"
```

And the output could be something like this:

```
+----------+-------+
|messageId |   id  |
+----------+-------+
|    1     |   4   |
|    17    |   5   |
|    7     |   6   |
|    29    |   7   |
|    18    |   8   |
|    19    |   9   |
+----------+-------+
```

As you can see, this is just a small result set, but if I have more than 1000 rooms with messages, it could become a large dataset, and fetching it all at once isn't efficient or necessary for the application.

So, I want to implement pagination using OFFSET and LIMIT.

For testing, I started with small pages.

I modified my query to paginate the data with 3 records in each page:

```
SELECT MAX
    ( "Messages"."id" ) AS messageId,
    "Rooms"."id" 
FROM
    "RoomUsers"
    INNER JOIN "Rooms" ON "RoomUsers"."roomId" = "Rooms"."id"
    INNER JOIN "Conversations" ON "Conversations"."roomId" = "Rooms"."id"
    INNER JOIN "Messages" ON "Messages"."conversationId" = "Conversations"."id" 
WHERE
    "RoomUsers"."userId" = 51
GROUP BY
    "Rooms"."id" 
    LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0
```

After running this query, this is the output:

```
+----------+-------+
|messageId |   id  |
+----------+-------+
|    1     |   4   |
|    17    |   5   |
|    7     |   6   |
+----------+-------+
```

It's okay just for this page. And if I add a page and change the offset to 1, this is the result:

```
+----------+-------+
|messageId |   id  |
+----------+-------+
|    17    |   5   |
|    7     |   6   |
|    29    |   7   |
+----------+-------+
```

And if I increase the offset's number and change it to 2, this is the next result:

```
+----------+-------+
|messageId |   id  |
+----------+-------+
|    7     |   6   |
|    29    |   7   |
|    18    |   8   |
+----------+-------+
```

So, what is going on here?

I couldn't understand the reason, and I need to paginate this data too!

What can I do, and how should I change it?

Comment: 1000 rooms with one user specified is not a large query; I don't see why you need pagination server side for something with 1000 rows. That's separate from display issues.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus What about more than 1000 rooms? Also, I'm encountering display issues, and I need to implement pagination, at least for the sake of UI.

Comment: I suggest you execute the full query at once and handle pagination on the front end. I certainly wouldn't go 3 at a time; round-trips to the server are expensive. I haven't done front-end in a long time, but even so, 1000 records is not a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 3 rows per page the offset needs to be 0, 3 and 6.

Also, the order of result is undeterministic without an `order by` clause. Add:

```
ORDER BY "Rooms"."id"
```

Comment: I tried with ordering but it didn't make any difference.. and about offset, Currently the pagination is based on limit and  I paginate it with multiplier of the limit number , so if I wanna to fetch 3 records in each page, the offset started from 0 and the next page is 6 and the next one is 9 and 12 and so on. Do you think this offsetting is ok?

Comment: In the question you mentioned using offset 0, 1 and 2. It needs to be 0 for page 1, 3 for page 2, 6 for page 3 and so on i.e. `(pagenumber - 1) * pagesize`

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has non-embedded SQL [`cursors`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-declare.html), and that's pretty much exactly what they're for. [Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/s8RXT0l5)

```sql
DECLARE messages_cursor CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR 
SELECT MAX
    ( "Messages"."id" ) AS messageId,
    "Rooms"."id" 
FROM
    "RoomUsers"
    INNER JOIN "Rooms" ON "RoomUsers"."roomId" = "Rooms"."id"
    INNER JOIN "Conversations" ON "Conversations"."roomId" = "Rooms"."id"
    INNER JOIN "Messages" ON "Messages"."conversationId" = "Conversations"."id" 
WHERE
    "RoomUsers"."userId" = 51
GROUP BY
    "Rooms"."id";
```

Run it once, and [`fetch`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-fetch.html) the results page by page:

```sql
FETCH FORWARD 3 FROM messages_cursor;
```

When you're done, [`close`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-close.html) it:

```sql
CLOSE messages_cursor;--/*if you want to clean them all up, then*/CLOSE ALL;
```

1. It saves you recomputing the whole thing each time, then sorting it each time, then throwing most of it out each time that repeated queries with progressing `offset` would do.
2. If you don't need the results to be sorted, you don't need to slow things down with the `order by`.
3. Cursor remains stable (`insensitive`) at all times, whereas any `delete`/`insert`/`update` applied to that table while you're in the process of reading pages, whacks `limit`/`offset` out of order.
4. `WITH HOLD` persists the cursor even if you have `autocommit` on, or need to run `commit`s between fetches in the same session. The only way to stabilise `limit`/`offset`-based pagination is to restrict it to a single [`repeatable read`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-REPEATABLE-READ) transaction, or dump it somewhere and read the dump, emulating the `cursor` behaviour ineffectively. `WITH HOLD` resorts to caching only if you `commit` before closing.

That being said, `cursor` is just a single notch up from `limit`/`offset` pagination - [there are other ways](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/).

Comment: It looks like it'll at some point get [added to sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10347) as something along the lines of `Model.findAllStream()` or `({stream: true})`, at which point you'll be able to just give it your `select` as-is and it'll handle the cursor for you.